# Does Map Control Need Application ID and Authentication Token

Tags: windows-phone-8

Wondering about the map implementation for Windows Phone 8 and 8.1. Users will be upgrading to 8.1 here soon and I want to be sure that my implementation will work on the OS when this occurs. Are there special requirements and changes to consider? Mainly I am interested in ensuring the map works before and after updating. Are there special requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say for sure whether the map controls will break if you don't implement the code with authentication from the store, since I've never tried it, but apparently it does not work. I can tell you for sure that I've uploaded apps with functioning map controls AND with authentication code, and the app functions fine on 8.1.

Here's how to authenticate your maps. First you need to start the upload process of your app to the store, including uploading your .xap file. Then before submitting the app, you'll have access to a "map services" function in the Dev Center that will allow you to request a map token.

Add this loaded event to each of your map controls in your app, providing the token you just obtained and the app's store ID.

```
private void myMapControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Phone.Maps.MapsSettings.ApplicationContext.ApplicationId = "ApplicationID";
        Microsoft.Phone.Maps.MapsSettings.ApplicationContext.AuthenticationToken = "AuthenticationToken";
    }
```

Then you just have to replace the old .xap you uploaded to the in-progress store submission with the new one you just modified to include the above code.

For more information, see: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207033(v=vs.105).asp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207033%28v=vs.105%29.asp)

Comment: Much appreciated. Could you provide any good references you've come across for creating authentication. Also, does this cost? Any information would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Edited my answer to include more info and a link for further reading. No you do not have to pay for authentication.

Comment: Is it possible to set this for all of the map controls in the app? E.g. in App.xaml.cs?

Comment: @Domas interesting question I'd like to know what you find out. I feel like setting this in `Application_Launching` of App.xaml.cs would do the trick.

Comment: @Domas No, you need to do each time a map is instantiated, that is why the examples use the Map control's Loaded event.